# How to position a html element relative to another html element using CSS or Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css, position, css-position

Is there any way to position a html element relative to another html element using CSS or Javascript ? Please check below code, I tried copying the the innerhtml of “second-element” and appended inside “first-element” , But this breaks other functionalities. So I need some CSS or JS fix without changing the HTML structure.

```
<body>
<div id=“first-element”>
    <p>— Select course —</p>
    <!— I need the second-element here —>
</div>

<div id=“second-element”> 
    <ul>
        <li>Maths<li>
        <li>Science</li>
    </ul>
</div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

```html
<div id="first-element">
  <p>— Select course —</p>
</div>
<div id="second-element">
  <ul>
    <li>Maths</li>
    <li>Science</li>
  </ul>
</div>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script> 
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
$('#second-element ul').appendTo('#first-element');
});

</script>
```

Comment: This solution is not suitable in my case, any way thanks for your suggestion.